# The best way to implement Offline Map in iOS

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios7, mapkit, mkoverlay

Can anyone suggest the best way to implement the offline map with following features.

- Add MKOverlayView with local static Map image
- Restrict to zoom outside the MKOverlay area
- Google Map should not appear on the screen
- Add multiple annotations of some fixed locations
- Tracking & rotating

I have used Mapkit framework to start of with & already added MKOverlayView in it. Now while adding few fixed annotations it doesn't allow to add without internet.

I don't think all above things can be achieved only using Mapkit framework. So can anyone suggest me the exact solution for it ?

Any suggestions of hints will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make map kit load map contents from a private map database. I don't remember if this is new in iOS 6 or 7. I want to say iOS 7. There was a WWDC session where an Apple engineer set up a private map as a demo.

Usually you'd host the map on a server and have your app download map tiles from the server. In your case you'd have it load tiles from a local directory on the device. However, map content gets big fast. You'd only be able to cover fairly modest areas before the file sizes of your map content became prohibitively large.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you look into MBXMapKit:

http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit

Comment: This one got deprecated now, any other proposals please?